# why do I get this error although I have an operator in my code?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

In MQL4, I have the following line

```
int OP_TYPE = int(0.5((1+f)*OP_BUY+(1-f)*OP_SELL));
```

which gives the error: `'+' - some operator expected`.

What am I supposed to do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot infer calc types using MQL4, make sure you explicitly type your calculation in full.

```
int OP_TYPE = int(0.5*((1+f)*OP_BUY+(1-f)*OP_SELL));
```